# In python shell, "b" letter does not work, what the?

Tags: python, shell

Well hello, this is the most interesting bug/conflict I've ever faced.

In python shell, I cannot type lowercase "b". At first I thought something was under the key, but no, in everywhere else it functions very well. Also `ctrl+b` `shift+b` even with `capslock b` works.

Yet more, when I run the shell with `sudo` (ie. `sudo python`), my little lowercase "b" works well.

My last move was installing pyexiv2 (using `aptitude`), I can import it without problems in both with and without sudo. I have removed it but the result didn't change.

What the hell might be wrong?

I am using `Ubuntu 10.04 LTS x86` with `Python 2.6.5`

Further note:
I have installed a vim modifier script which *might* be the trouble.
Using this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sontek/dotfiles.git
$ cd dotfiles
$ ./install.sh vim
```

This scripts initiates more git clones, so it might be hard to follow. But it ***does*** many changes including the terminal's look.

### ***UPDATE***:

1) I even cannot copy/paste "b" character. `ctrl+c/v` `select&middle click` both doesnt work.

2) When I open the shell with `python -E`, the modifiers from the mentioned *so called* `vim script` does not appear. And `b` works well. When I open it with `python` or `python -S` the modifications exists and i cannot type `b`.

**3**) *Good news*: I have managed to locate the fault, it is the *so called* `vim script`. I have renamed its folder and it worked fine. In couple of hours, I will examine deeply what exactly causes the problem and post it here with detailed results.

Comment: in `python -E` it works. in `python -S` it does not. what does -E, -S?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/297527/problem-by-b-letter-in-python-shell-in-mac

Comment: It is most probably same bug, but I am using python in Ubuntu. There is no answer in there also, so I keep the topic. Might be migrated to superuser, though. And, I have followed the instructions in the link and came across something. I am adding to main question in a second.

Comment: Use `strace -t open` or its equivalent on your system to find out what file Python is trying to open (which would mess it up) but now cannot.  Maybe it's `inputrc`, that would explain it.

Comment: Need to remember this when it comes time to play a practical joke.

Comment: Well, I removed `~/.inputrc` file and it worked for me. I had couple of keys bind there.

Comment: Thank you for asking this. Most annoying thing ever!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My money is that the readline on your shell is messed up.  Perhaps the 'b' key is bound to auto-complete.  Look in your `PYTHONSTARTUP` variable and see what file it refers to.  If that file has something like `readline.parse_and_bind` ...

I'm betting there's some connection between the fact that it's 'b' (instead of some other letter) and the word 'bind', like there's a variable called `bind_to_complete` and it's being interpreted literally (and only the first character taken).

Let the mass wild-ass guessing commence!

Comment: `readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")`  
`readline.parse_and_bind ("bind ^I rl_complete")`
It only has this. complete script is at: http://pastebin.com/zmz3c0yN

Comment: Ok. `readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")` causes the bug to occur. But HOW? how can `^I = b`?

Comment: I notices the command "tab: complete" binds the key 'tab' to function 'complete'; perhaps the command 'bind ^I rl_complete' binds the key 'b" to the (nonexistent) function 'ind ^I rl_complete'.  That was my guess in my response and that's my guess now.

Comment: Yes, 15 seconds of experimentation yields the observation that `readline.parse_and_bind("xyz')` prevents the `x` character, whatever it is, from working.  Presumably, there's some value of `yz` that would cause pressing `x` to do something useful, but random characters just stop it from doing anything at all.  I hate to say I told you so but ... wait, strike that, I *love* saying I told you so.  I even have an obnoxious gloating dance I do.

Comment: Respect. So, what would be correct way to use `rl_complete` as a shortcut. What `^I` tried to mean?

Comment: No idea.  I tried a few things, but nothing.  If only there were some place you could ask technical questions of the community at large, perhaps on a world-wide communication network of some sort...

Answer (score 14):

The problematic line in your `.pythonstartup` is something like:

```
 readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete") # darwin libedit
```

This `.pythonstartup` will fix it...

```
try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    print "Module readline not available."
else:
    import rlcompleter
    if 'libedit' in readline.__doc__:
        readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")
    else:
        readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```